# Monitor notebook power consumption on Windows 7 x64

Tags: battery, power-management, power-consumption, laptop

there is this nifty tool called NHC (Notebook Hardware Control) for 32 bit notebooks which also shows the current power consumption.

Now I have a 64 bit laptop where NHC doesn't work. Is there any way to see the current wattage without using a meter on the power adapter's plug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/index.html

This seems to run on Win7 x64. I didn't find anything contrary to that.
I have yet to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

ThinkPads have this as standard.

You can give [Notebook Battery Info](http://www.batteryinfo.co.cc/) a try.

[image: Notebook Battery Info]

Comment: No workie. I had to go to http://batteryinfo.x10hosting.com/html/ to download first of all... The .co.cc which just has a frame to the same folder gives me a forbidden when trying to download, strangely. Installation says: 64bit OS detected, cannot be installed on a 64 bit os.

Comment: @sinni800: Oh, no x64 version?  That sucks.